# Spigot broke on primary fermentation bucket

Tags: fermentation

After 6 days in primary I went to move bucket and the spigot broke. Managed to keep it in place while attaching a hose and transferring the wort. There was a ring around the top of the bucket where the liquid was and very little sediment at the bottom. It's been in a glass carboy for 24 hours now and there is about 1 & 1/2 inch of foam at the top as well as a lot of sediment at the bottom with a fair amount of movement, no clarity at all. (English Ale) Am I screwed ? 1 st batch obviously.

Comment: Please help. Don't want to lose this....

Comment: Thank you very much... I'm certainly not like most first timers that are in a hurry. Is it best to just leave it for a couple weeks or more?  Temp range has been Btwn 63 & 70 the entire time... Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Shawn, there's a good chance everything will be fine.  You might as well let things go to completion and find out for sure.  For future reference, I'd recommend buckets without spigots for fermenting.  Besides the drawback you discovered, I've found it's difficult to keep the spigots cleaned and sanitized enough to use the for xfers.

Comment: Thank you very much... I'm certainly not like most first timers that are in a hurry. Is it best to just leave it for a couple weeks or more? Temp range has been Btwn 63 & 70 the entire time... Really appreciate your time. – Shawn just now edit

Comment: I almost always leave the beer in a primary for 3-4 weeks and skip a secondary.  Patience seems to be the best advice.